# Inaccurate Simulated Metrics for Landscape Navigation Bar

Tags: xcode4, interface-builder, uinavigationbar, xib, landscape

It seems that the simulated metrics for a view with a navigation bar are based on the dimensions of the **portrait mode** navigation bar. When the app is compiled and run, landscape navigation bars are actually slimmer (less high) than they are in portrait mode.

Is there any clean way to fix this other than to programmatically add my navigation bar while putting a slim placeholder nav bar in my XIB, while forgoing simulated metrics? That would be a shame because I like using simulated metrics.